# Uniform convergence of difference coefficients

Tags: real-analysis

The function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Define the sequence of functions $\{g_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as $$g_n(x)=n\left(f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)\right)$$
Obviously if $f$ is differentiable then $g_n(x)\rightarrow f'(x)$. When will be this convergence uniform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the mean value theorem one has

$$g_n(x) = f^\prime\left(x + \frac{\theta(x, n)}{n}\right)$$

with $\theta(x, n)\in (0, 1)$.

It means that $g_n\to f^\prime$ uniformly if $f^\prime$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: thanks. is there any weaker condition?

Answer (score 4):

As a compliment for @Gribouillis answer, take $f(x)=x^{3}$ which $f'(x)=3x^{2}$ is not uniformly continuous, then $n(f(x+1/n)-f(x))=3x^{2}+3n^{-1}x+n^{-2}$ does not converge uniformly to $x\rightarrow 3x^{2}$.